# git merge-base --fork-point <ref> is yielding nothing

Tags: git, git-merge

I am running this on a feature branch:

```
git fetch origin
git merge-base --fork-point origin/dev; echo $?
```

the `git merge-base` command is exiting with 1, but logging zero stdout/stderr.

I can't figure out why the `merge-base` command wouldn't yield a ref, anyone know why that might happen?

Comment: See the caveats at the bottom of the fork-point documentation on [the `git merge-base` page](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html). There are numerous conditions under which Git cannot find a suitable base.

Comment: Use `git merge-base HEAD origin/dev` instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The caveats mentioned by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) are part of the [`git merge-base` discussion on fork-point mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#_discussion_on_fork_point_mode).

> ```
>          o---B2
>         /
> ---o---o---B1--o---o---o---B (origin/master)
>     \                   \
>      B0                  D0'--D1'--D' (topic - updated)
>       \
>        D0---D1---D (topic - old)
> ```
>
> A caveat is that **older reflog entries in your repository may be expired by `git gc`**.
>   If `B0` no longer appears in the reflog of the remote-tracking branch `origin/master`, the `--fork-point` mode obviously cannot find it and fails, avoiding to give a random and useless result (such as the parent of B0, like the same command without the `--fork-point` option gives).
>
> Also, **the remote-tracking branch you use the `--fork-point` mode with must be the one your topic forked from its tip**.
>   If you forked from an older commit than the tip, this mode would not find the fork point (imagine in the above sample history `B0` did not exist, `origin/master` started at `B1`, moved to `B2` and then `B`, and you forked your `topic` at `origin/master^` when `origin/master` was `B1`; the shape of the history would be the same as above, without `B0`, and the parent of `B1` is what `git merge-base origin/master topic` correctly finds, but the `--fork-point` mode will not, because it is not one of the commits that used to be at the tip of `origin/master`).

You can see additional scenario where `git merge-base --fork-point` doesn't work [in this thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqq375okvxy.fsf@gitster.mtv.corp.google.com/T/).
[This patch series](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqq375okvxy.fsf@gitster.mtv.corp.google.com/) illustrate the current documentation.